# tools package - "Installed file does not exist"

Tags: miktex, latexmk, compilation-error

After updating all the packages in my MiKTeX 2.9 installation (the last update was 03/2018), the compilation of a document that apparently uses the `tools` package does not work anymore.
The mpm reinstalls the already installed package, then a fatal error occurs (excerpt from *pdflatex.log*):

> 2018-07-05 14:00:55,106+0200 FATAL pdflatex - The installed file does not exist.
>
> 2018-07-05 14:00:55,106+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\.tex"
>
> 2018-07-05 14:00:55,106+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\findfile.cpp
>
> 2018-07-05 14:00:55,106+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 55
>
> 2018-07-05 14:00:55,107+0200 INFO  pdflatex - finishing with exit code 1

The respective folder is not empty and contains 41 files (which I am not gonna list).
I have tried removing the tools package and reinstalling it myself to no avail.

I write and compile my documents in TeXstudio 2.12.8 using latexmk as my default compiler with the following command:

```
latexmk.exe -r latexmkrc -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex %%O %%S" %
```

This has been working fine up until the update.

What can I do?

PS: I fear, this might be the wrong place to ask this kind of question. If so, please advise me as to where I should turn to and I will remove the question myself.

Comment: Indeed last MiKTeX update of tools is missing `.tex`.  You can download the ready-to-install `latex-tools.tds.zip`, extract the missing file  and place it in `MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools`, then refresh the FNDB from MiKTeX Console, ` Tasks` menu.

Comment: That worked, but how can this file be missing? Now also relsize.sty is missing from ltxmisc. 

Comment: Errors in packaging can happen, and adding an issue to the miktex tracker was the right thing to do.

Comment: True it happens. It also said `ltxmisc\relsize.sty` was missing and wanted to reinstall `ltxmisc`, which does not contain the file. Installing the `relsize` package fixed it.

Comment: Then you perhaps should update your package database.

Comment: Of course, I did multiple times on my way to fix this issue. Danke trotzdem!